# Prevent form from showing multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

In windows form (c#), i am showing a form when user click on button, it is working fine form is visible to user, but if user click again on the same button the same form is opening again two forms are displaying. Is there any way to prevent this, please give me any reference for this thank you. This is my code....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 obj = new Form2();
  obj.Show();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for your button `Click` handler, where you are showing the new form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are most likely doing something like this:

```
void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var newForm = new MyForm();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

So you are showing a new instance of the form every time it is clicked.  You want to do something like this:

```
MyForm _form = new MyForm();

void button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _form.Show();
}
```

Here you have just *one* instance of the form you wish to show, and just Show() it.

Comment: yeah you r right, now i understand, i am new to windows app. thank you Mr. Jonathon

Comment: Great!!  Nice solution

Comment: If you close the _form, it's gone forever. Click on the button will throw an exception. Better set a bool formShowing to true in the constructor of the _form and set the bool to false in the Form_Closing event delegate of it. In the button click part, Show the _form unless the bool is already true.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (form.GetType() == typeof(MyFormType))
    {
        form.Activate();
        return;
    }
}

Form newForm = new MyFormType();
newForm.MdiParent = this;
newForm.Show();
```

i tried more than a ways to compare which one is better.

but i think this solution must be better than the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
    private Form f;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f == null)
        {
            f = new Form();
            f.Closed += f_Closed;
            f.Show();
        }
    }

    void f_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably creating a new instance of the form every time in the Click handler of the Button.

So you ill need to move the Form object creation outside the `Button_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example of a proven solution
This will open the form if it is not already open.
If it is already open, it will place it in the foreground.

```
namespace MainProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form formNew = new FormToShowSomething();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formNew.Show();
            formNew.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution to your problem is replacing the Show command with ShowDialog, that way you won't any problem when it comes to preventing a form to show up twice

```
Form2 obj = new Form2();
obj.ShowDialog();
```

the code: `.ShowDialog();` is what we are currently looking for that will solve the issue

Comment: If Ssasidhar wants Show() and NOT ShowDialog() there is a reason. Preemptive forms are not the solution. And there are many solutions: see Adriaan, or mine above in response at Jonathan, for example.

Answer (score 0):

10 years after , like the band :p
Thought to share the code that works for me. Nothing fancy, just checking if the form instance exists. Also, I don't prefer the ShowDialog, because the user is 'trapped' in that form and I find it annoying. The user might want to check other info from another source, for example when filling an online form and needs to copy paste a field info.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var obj = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Select(t => t).FirstOrDefault();
 if (obj != null)
   {
      obj.BringToFront();
   }
 else
   {
      obj = new Form2();
      obj.Show();
   }
}
```