# Prevent a Window from beeing opened multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a pop up window in c#. I have a button and when the user clicks the button the window pops up. My problem is that if the user happens to click the button multiple times, the window will be opened multiple times. Once the user has opened the window, I do not want the window to be opened again if the user clicks the button. Is this possible to achieve?

My make the window pop up like this:

```
PopUp myPopUp = new PopUp(); 
myPopUp.show();
```

I am using wpf.

Comment: You haven't even bothered to tell us what GUI API you're using. The obvious answer is, keep a variable that tracks whether the window is already open, and don't open it again. That variable could even just be the reference to the window, making it easy activate. I'm sure the question you want to ask is already answered on Stack Overflow, but the question you posted is so vague, it's not even possible to know which duplicate question is the right one.

Comment: I searched the internet and couldn't find an answer to my question. I am new to this so I'm sorry if my question was vague, I'll think of this in my future questions

Comment: also you can disable the button first, then pop up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775140/prevent-form-from-showing-multiple-times    And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018272/preventing-multiple-instance-of-one-form-from-displaying

Comment: @ShemeerBK I am using wpf, not forms.

Comment: @Anna , declare the variable in as global and and call the show event when you want in the trigger.its same anyway.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user needs to access the main window after the popup opened I would create a class member, that holds a reference to the popup and on closing the popup set that reference to `null`:

```
PopPp myPopUp = null;

private void OpenPopUp()
{
    if(myPopUp == null)
    {
        myPopUp = new PopUp();
        myPopUp.Closed += (x,y) => { myPopUp = null; };
        myPopUp.Show();
    }
}
```

If the user does not need to interact with the main window, while the popup is opened just use `ShowDialog`. It will prevent any input to the main window until the popup is closed:

```
PopUp myPopUp = new PopUp(); 
myPopUp.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I am using wpf and not forms, so I'm not sure that your first example will work..

Comment: I've edited my answer to work with WPF. You should always include the UI Framework you use as a tag when asking a question.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I'll think of that when I write my future questions. Guess I was too quick when I was writing this one.

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to use `ShowDialog` instead for `Show`, then the user need to close the popup in order to click the button again. so the code will be :

```
PopUp myPopUp = new PopUp(); 
myPopUp.ShowDialog();
```

Or else you have to disable the button after first click by using `buttonName.Enabled = !buttonName.Enabled;` in this case you have to find the point at which button needs to enabled back.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using ShowDialog solved my problem :) I appreciate your help!

Comment: But now I can't interact with my main window. @un-lucky

Comment: @Anna In easy language: ShowDialog is by default Top-most. you can't do anything unless you dispose(close) the Window that has been called using showDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Like in-lucky said, the best option is to use `ShowDialog`. However, if you don't want it to be a modal dialog, you can us `Application.Current.Windows` which gives you the list of open forms in your applications. Then check if your form is in the list before you show it with your code. Something like this:

```
if(Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
   .Where(x => x.Name == "myPopUpName").FirstOrDefault() == null){
  PopUp myPopUp = new PopUp(); 
  myPopUp.show();
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to hardcode the name of the form, you can do it like this:

```
PopUp myPopUp = new PopUp(); 
if(Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
   .Where(x => x.Name == myPopUp.Name).FirstOrDefault() == null){
  myPopUp.show();
}
```

But this wastes some resources because it creates a new copy of the form and then discards it if already open.

Comment: I am not using forms, but wpf. But thank you! @RacilHilan

Comment: Then you can use `Application.Current.Windows` instead of `Application.OpenForms`. See my updated answer.